# How can I create a gradient on a rectangular div with repeating lines at a 45 degree angle in opposite directions?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, web, frontend

I want to create a gradient with lines moving in both directions, but at a 45 degree angle. with html and css.
[image: this is what I managed to produce]
How can I do the same lines, but in an opposite direction.

This is the code I used below to produce the image above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

<style>
  .repeating-linear {
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    -45deg,
    black 4px,
    transparent,
    transparent 10px
  );

}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="repeating-linear" style="width: 200px;height: 50px; border: 1px solid red;">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have yo tried to change -45deg to 45deg ?

Comment: So basically you want a "cross" pattern, lines going at 45deg to cross with lines going at -45deg? Then add a _second_ gradient.

Comment: @JiaSH Hi yes I had a duplicate of that code but with an opposite direction of the angle like you are suggesting, but only the last gradient is considered in this case. and yes I wan t a gradient going in 45deg and a second one going in -45deg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want cross lines, you can stack gradients as proposed below:

```
<div class='repeating-linear' />

.repeating-linear{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px; 
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: 
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      -45deg,
      black 4px,
      transparent,
      transparent 10px
    ),
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      45deg,
      black 4px,
      transparent,
      transparent 10px
    );
}
```

jsfiddle sample: https://jsfiddle.net/4rL7n8xo/

result:
[image]

Comment: @T.Joseph you don't need a different element per gradient. You can stack gradients: https://jsfiddle.net/4rL7n8xo/

Comment: The solution in the comment above is better than mine :)